# What is the easiest way to compare 2 tensorflow graphs stored in .meta files

Tags: tensorflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Given 2 TensorFlow graph metadata files (graph1.meta and graph2.meta) what would be the easiest way to compare the structure of the graphs?

Namely, there might be a way to feed .meta file to TensorBoard. Or maybe there is a converter to plain text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you suggest, you could export it to a text format. Using `export_meta_graph` with the option `as_text=True`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/meta_graph

```
def export_meta_graph(filename=None, collection_list=None, as_text=False):
  """Writes `MetaGraphDef` to save_path/filename.

  Args:
    filename: Optional meta_graph filename including the path.
    collection_list: List of string keys to collect.
    as_text: If `True`, writes the meta_graph as an ASCII proto.

  Returns:
    A `MetaGraphDef` proto.
  """
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing the best way would be to visualize both graphs in tensorboard.
steps:

1. import the graph using `import_meta_graph` function
2. export the model to a .pb file using the [freeze_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) tool.
3. create tensorboard logs for graph inspection using the [import_pb_to_tensorboard](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/import_pb_to_tensorboard.py) tool. usage example:

   ```
   python PATH_TO_YOUR_TENSORFLOW _INSTALLATION/tensorflow/python/tools/import_pb_to_tensorboard.py --model_dir PATH_TO_PB_FILE --log_dir TEMP_TENSORBOARD_DIR
   ```
4. open tensorboard and view the graph:

   `tensorboard --logdir=TEMP_TENSORBOARD_DIR`

That way you can inspect both graphs and inspect them visually.